# How can I describe smooth curved line and sharped corner graph in Echarts?

Tags: javascript, echarts

I'd like to depict a graph like the one in the image using Javascript. It has smooth curved line and sharped corner.　I'm going to use Echarts to describe it, which is very flexible. Of course, it is possible to just describe the smooth lines. Just type like this. `type:'line', smooth:true,`

But I want to clearly describe the corners of the line chart. Is there a way to depict this in Echarts or a library that can do this kind of depiction?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using the following information available in the documentation:

- [ECharts Basic Concepts Overview](https://echarts.apache.org/en/tutorial.html#ECharts%20Basic%20Concepts%20Overview)
- [grid](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#grid)
- [grid.show](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#grid.show)
- [Ascombe's quartet - editor demo](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=scatter-anscombe-quartet)

And, by using the editor in Echarts, I was able to create this sample - you can modify it for your purposes.

Basically, you have to set provide these values in the chart's settings:

Example:

```
option = {
    title: {
        text: 'Anscombe\'s quartet',
        left: 'center',
        top: 0
    },
    grid: [{
        left: '7%',
        top: '7%',
        width: '38%',
        height: '38%',
        borderWidth: 1, // Width of the rectangle that is made of by xAxis and yAxis.
        show: true, // Required.
        borderColor: "#000000" // Color of the rectangle that is made of by xAxis and yAxis.
    }],
```

Hope it helps:

```js
var dom = document.getElementById("container");
var myChart = echarts.init(dom);
var app = {};

var option;



var dataAll = [
  [
    [10.0, 8.04],
    [8.0, 6.95],
    [13.0, 7.58],
    [9.0, 8.81],
    [11.0, 8.33],
    [14.0, 9.96],
    [6.0, 7.24],
    [4.0, 4.26],
    [12.0, 10.84],
    [7.0, 4.82],
    [5.0, 5.68]
  ]
];

var markLineOpt = {
  animation: false,
  label: {
    formatter: 'y = 0.5 * x + 3',
    align: 'right'
  },
  lineStyle: {
    type: 'solid'
  },
  tooltip: {
    formatter: 'y = 0.5 * x + 3'
  },
  data: [
    [{
      coord: [0, 3],
      symbol: 'none'
    }, {
      coord: [20, 13],
      symbol: 'none'
    }]
  ]
};

option = {
  title: {
    text: 'Anscombe\'s quartet',
    left: 'center',
    top: 0
  },
  grid: [{
    left: '7%',
    top: '7%',
    width: '38%',
    height: '38%',
    borderWidth: 1,
    show: true,
    borderColor: "#000000"
  }],
  tooltip: {
    formatter: 'Group {a}: ({c})'
  },
  xAxis: [{
    gridIndex: 0,
    min: 0,
    max: 20
  }],
  yAxis: [{
    gridIndex: 0,
    min: 0,
    max: 15
  }],
  series: [{
    name: 'I',
    type: 'scatter',
    xAxisIndex: 0,
    yAxisIndex: 0,
    data: dataAll[0],
    markLine: markLineOpt
  }]
};

if (option && typeof option === 'object') {
  myChart.setOption(option);
}
```

```html
<!--
    THIS EXAMPLE WAS DOWNLOADED FROM https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=scatter-anscombe-quartet
-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="height: 100%">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body style="height: 100%; margin: 0">
  <div id="container" style="height: 100%"></div>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/echarts-nightly@5.1.2-dev.20210512/dist/echarts.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```